# TextField Button action is not working

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I created custom class LoginView.cs UIView For username and password added the loginButton.

now I added UIView Call into my LoginViewController.cs Class

When i build and run the application it shows the login box, two text fields and a button. The actions on the textfield are not working. When the textbox has focus the keyboard doesn't load

This is my custom View class for loginview.cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Drawing;     
    using MonoTouch.Foundation;
    using MonoTouch.UIKit;

    namespace DemoHouse
    {
        class LoginView : UIView
        {      
              UIView view_Login;
              UITextField txt_username;
            public readonly UITextField txt_password;

            public readonly UIButton btn_Login;

            public LoginView (string loginView){

                float frame = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;

                Add (view_Login = new UIView (new RectangleF (20, 60,frame-40, 200)) {
                    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red,

                });

                float subFrame = view_Login.Bounds.Width;

                view_Login.AddSubview(txt_username = new UITextField (new RectangleF (20, 20, subFrame-40, 31)){

                    BackgroundColor = UIColor.White,
                });

                view_Login.AddSubview(txt_password = new UITextField (new RectangleF (20, 70, subFrame-40, 31)){

                    BackgroundColor = UIColor.White
                });

                view_Login.AddSubview (btn_Login = new UIButton (new RectangleF (20, 120, 60, 31)) {

                    BackgroundColor = UIColor.Blue
                });

            }

        }
    }
```

This is LoginViewController.cs

```
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;

namespace DemoHouse
{
    public partial class LoginViewController : UIViewController
    {
        LoginView loginView;
        UIScrollView scrollView;

        public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning (){
            // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
            base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning ();

            // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
        }

        #region View lifecycle



        public override void ViewDidLoad ()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad ();
            loginView = new LoginView("LoginView");
            View.AddSubview (loginView);

            // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        }
```

Let me know if something is wrong.
Is this the correct approach?
I do not want to use storyboard and xib in my application.

@All 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you want to rephrase the question to something a bit more specific, since this site is not meant as a place to get your code debugged. Maybe [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is what you are looking for?

Comment: @MarcusWigert My question is not mean for code review.  I had issue when I created custom view.  added in view controller.  Default in iOS when added textfield it will open the keyboard listener.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a silly solution, but add a tap gesture to the button.

```
login_btn.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
login_btn.AddGestureRecognizer (new UITapGestureRecognizer(()=>{
//Action In HERE
}));
```

Comment: its not triggering the event.

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard popping up is a native functionality, so I am in awe you managed to break it. Maybe you should try not to condensate your code so much. It makes for less lines of code, but also causes readability and complexity to increase. Also, why not merge both classes? You already have a `ViewController` class. Try something like this:

```
public partial class LoginViewController : UIViewController
{
    private UIScrollView scrollView;

    private UITextField txt_username, txt_password;
    private UIButton btn_login;

    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        /*Depending on what else is on the screen, you can hard-code the 
        x, y, width and height, but in all other cases, use this:*/
        scrollView = new UIScrollView (this.View.Bounds);

        txt_username = new UITextField (new RectangleF (5, 5, 50, 25));
        //Change other properties of the UITextfield to your liking here.
        txt_password = new UITextField (new RectangleF (5, 35, 50, 25));
        //Change other properties of the UITextfield to your liking here.

        btn_login = new UIButton (new RectangleF (5, 65, 50, 25));
        btn_login.TouchUpInside += Login;
        //Change other properties of the UIButton to your liking here.

        this.View.AddSubview (scrollView);

        scrollView.AddSubviews (new UIView[]{txt_username, txt_password, btn_login});
    }

    void Login (object sender, eventargs e)
    {
        //Do something on button click
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that with this solution, you won't actually be able to scroll down with the scrollView, because the `scrollView.ContentSize` is not set. You could implement a method, where the framesizes of all controls are set. You call this method when changing orientation (in the `ViewDidRotate` method). You can also add the `scrollView.ContentSize` in this method.

I hope this information helps. Good luck!